# ASP.NET Automated deployment to remote ftp server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, automated-deploy

Does anyone know any good solutions for automated deployment to a remote server using SFTP? I am specifically trying to deploy an asp.net mvc website to mosso. I can do it manually every time using an SFTP client, but would much rather have an automated (and consistent) way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have written a pretty detailed blog post using TeamCity, and Web Deployment projects to automate build and deployment as a starter here:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/05/09/automated-site-deployments-with-teamcity-deployment-projects-amp-svn

I have then added to this to show FTP addition

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/09/21/continuous-integration-tip-1-ndash-ftp-deployment

A basic process flow is pretty simple:

- Using a teamcity build server i download from my SVN repo
- I build and deploy the site to a local folder on the build server
- I fire a command line FTP client that supports scripting called
- WinSCP using the MSBUILD Task EXEC  (http://winscp.net/)
- Upload all my sites content
- Have [insert beverage] of choice

I then make sure that i only deploy the Trunk of my SVN repo, and develop and test everything in an branch before merging - this way only tested stuff gets deployed. Add Automated testing to your build cycle and you've got a match made in heaven.

Some great free tools to get going are:

- [Visual Studio Web Deployment Project](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=89F2C4F5-5D3A-49B6-BCAD-F776C6EDFA63&amp%3Bdisplaylang=en)
- [TeamCity (free for under 20 build configs)](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)
- [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/)

Answer (score 3):

[deployment tools under .NET solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416573/deployment-tools-under-net-solutions)
[Automatic Deployment Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231283/automatic-deployment-resources)